# The limit of the difference quotient and the absolute value of the Jacobian

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. My question is, is there any relationship between 
$$
\lim_{y-x}\frac{\|f(y) - f(x)\|}{\|y-x\|}
$$
and the absolute value of the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$ denoted by $\vert J_f(x) \vert$?

In particular, I'm interested in the existence of a constant $C = C(n,f) > 0$ such that
$$
\liminf_{y-x}\frac{\|f(x) - f(y)\|}{\|y-x\|} \leq C \vert J_f(x) \vert.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a go at the answer.  Firstly 
$$ \lim_{y \to x} \inf \frac{||f(x) - f(y)||}{||x - y ||} \leq \lim \frac{||f(x + ut) - f(x)||}{t} = Df(u)
$$
where $u$ is a unit vector.  So $C = 1$ works for $n=1$.  Consider the case where the derivative matrix has non-zero determinant.  For $n=2$, let $u_1 = \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}/||u||, u_2 = -\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}/||u||$ 
$$
\left|\left| \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}u_1 + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}u_2
\\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}u_1 +  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}u_2
\end{pmatrix} \right|\right| = \frac{1}{(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1})^2 + (\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2})^2}\left|\left| \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}) + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}(-\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1})
\\ 0
\end{pmatrix} \right|\right| = \frac{\det Df}{(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1})^2 + (\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2})^2}
$$

For greater dimensions, we can do something similar with the normalized vector of cofactors.

$$ \lim_{y \to x} \inf \frac{||f(x) - f(y)||}{||x - y ||} \leq \frac{\det Df}{||(A_1, \dots A_n)||}
$$
Where $A_i$ is the ith cofactor of the derivative matrix.

Otherwise, in the case where the matrix has zero determinant, the derivative matrix has a nullspace so we can find a vector in which direction the derivative is zero and hence $$ \lim_{y \to x} \inf \frac{||f(x) - f(y)||}{||x - y ||} = 0 $$